# Parceable causes Stackoverflow

Tags: android, parcelable, stack-overflow

There is two classes, link each other someway. Problem is having Stackoverflow exception if I implements Parceable this way:

> **RSSFeed.java**

```
 public class RSSFeed implements Parcelable {
    private String title;
    private String link;
    private ArrayList<RSSItem> rssItems;

public RSSFeed() {
    rssItems = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringArray(new String[] { this.title, this.link });
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelableArrayList("rssItems", rssItems);
    dest.writeBundle(b);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<RSSFeed> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<RSSFeed>() {
    @Override
    public RSSFeed createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        RSSFeed rssFeed = new RSSFeed();

        String[] data = new String[2];
        in.readStringArray(data);
        rssFeed.title = data[0];
        rssFeed.link = data[1];

        Bundle b = in.readBundle(RSSItem.class.getClassLoader());
        rssFeed.rssItems = b.getParcelableArrayList("rssItems");
        return rssFeed;
    }

    @Override
    public RSSFeed[] newArray(int size) {
        return new RSSFeed[size];
    }
};
```

> **RSSItem.java**

```
public class RSSItem implements Parcelable {
private RSSFeed feed;
private String title;

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("feed", this.feed);
    dest.writeStringArray(new String[] { this.title });
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<RSSItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<RSSItem>() {
    @Override
    public RSSItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        RSSItem rssItem = new RSSItem();

        Bundle b = in.readBundle(RSSFeed.class.getClassLoader());
        rssItem.feed = b.getParcelable("feed");

        String[] dataString = new String[1];
        in.readStringArray(dataString);
        rssItem.setTitle(dataString[0]);

        return rssItem;
    }

    @Override
    public RSSItem[] newArray(int size) {
        return new RSSItem[size];
    }
};
```

So, it crushes with stackoverflow I guess because it's trying in `writeParcel(...)` to pass `ArrayList<RSSItems>` which one in `writeParcel(...)` try to pass `RSSFeed` member and again and again. So, the question is how to solve this problem to Parce two classes?

Comment: and exact stacktrace is?

Answer (score 1):

You have cycles in your object graph. Your `RSSFeed` put `RSSItem`s  in the parcel, an `RSSItem` puts the parent `RSSFeed` in the parcel. Do not parcel one of these dependencies to kill the cycle. Usually the parent relationship i.e. from item to feed should not be parceled.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I wrote that I know that is cycling. I just hope that there is a right way to do that. I use both RSSFeed and RSSItem classes to pass between Activities, so I need to get RSSFeed item from RSSItem class. If I dont Parcel 'RSSFeed feed' in RSSItem I will miss it when I pass it to another activity, no?